# Can I "take a break" from a multicolumn environment for a TikZ figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, multicol

A similar question has been asked before: [How can I escape a multicolumn environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237469/how-can-i-escape-a-multicolumn-environment), but the answers are not sufficient.

I would like to insert a `tikzpicture` in the middle of a `multicols` environment, specifically two column. If I end and restart `multicols` it doesn't display correctly.

I would like the left column to skip past the figure through to the next part of the left column and then into the beginning of the right column, skip past the figure into the second part of the right column.

Comment: I know of no package that will accomplish this automatically.  You can accomplish it manually by inserting the graphic in the intended location in the first column (making it look like it's only one column wide), then continuing the text, and manually inserting an "empty box" at the corresponding location in the second column.  Obviously, if earlier text changes, everything has to be repositioned.  A pain, but it can be done.

Comment: You might have better luck with flowfram, but it would take a lot of work.  BRW, are we talking 2 or 3 columns?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512455/two-column-with-a-text-box-in-the-center-wrapping-on-both-sides

Answer (score 1):

This is only valid for individual pages or independent text fragments. In this case a `tcbposter` environment from `tcolorbox` package allows to decide how a fragmented text is placed along several boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
poster = {height=10cm,spacing=2mm,rows=3, columns=2},
boxes= {blankest},
]
\posterbox[]{name=fig,column=1,row=2,span=2}{\centering\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{example-image-a}}
\posterbox{name=C, sequence=1 between top and fig then
1 between fig and bottom then
2 between top and fig then 2 between fig and bottom
}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329709/how-to-put-figure-at-middle-or-at-desired-position-on-a-page/531802?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C40.4152#531802 interesting.